# (j)Unit testing assertions and error messages?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assert

I am currently testing a method, let me call it `testedMethod()`.

The body of the method looks like this

```
private testedMethod(List<Protocoll> protocolList) {
    //so something with the protocolList
    if (something) && (somethingElse) {
        Assert.isFalse(areTheProtocollsCorrect(p1, p2), "Error, the protocols are wrong");
    }

    if (somethingCompeletlyElse) && (somethingElse) {
        Assert.isFalse(areTheProtocollsExactlyTheSame(p1, p2), "Error, the protocols are the same");
    }
}
```

Additional code from the `Assert.class`:

isFalse:

```
public static void isFalse(boolean condition, String descr) {
    isTrue(!condition, descr);
}
```

isTrue:

```
public static void isTrue(boolean condition, String descr) {
    if (!condition) {
        fail(descr);
    }
}
```

fail:

```
public static void fail(String descr) {
    LOGGER.fatal("Assertion failed: " + descr);
    throw new AssertException(descr);
}
```

Testing what the method should do correctly is allready done. But I would like to test those assertions. This assertions are an important part of the code, and I would like to see if the method is throwing those errors when I provide wrong data to it. How can I do it using JUnit?

Comment: You have jUnit `Assert` in your code? Is it Spring `Assert`? If Spring, check for `IAE`s.

Comment: What does `Assert.isFalse()` do? If it's your own code you should include it in the question.

Comment: @kryger @Dave Newton - I have added the methods from `Assert.class`

Comment: So check for the exception. I don't understand what the issue is, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, I you are currently using JUnit, you shouldn't code your own `assert*` or `fail` methods: They are already included in the [Assert](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) class.

Anyway, if you want to test your assertions, you have to code two kind of test cases: positive cases and negative (failing) cases:

```
@Test
public void positiveCase1()
{
    // Fill your input parameters with data that you know must work:
    List<Protocoll> protocolList=...
    testedMethod(protocolList);
}

@Test
public void positiveCase2()
{
    ...
}

@Test(expected=AssertException.class)
public void negativeCase1()
{
    // Fill your input parameters with data that you know must NOT work:
    List<Protocoll> protocolList=...
    testedMethod(protocolList);
}

@Test(expected=AssertException.class)
public void negativeCase2()
{
    ...
}
```

The `expected` parameter in the `Test` annotation makes JUnit check that an exception of that type was raised. Else, the test is marked as *failed*.

But I still insist in that it's better to use the JUnit standards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still, I am using the JUnit assertions. The other assertions in my code have completely other purpose and they are not used in JUnit tests :)

Comment: OK. In that case, my answer will fit for your case.